# MvvmCross Visibility plugin does not hide my TextView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to make an item invisible using MvvmCross Visibility plugin. I am using MvvmCross 5.7 and MvvmCross Visibility plugin 5.7.

I tried to bind the visibility of the object both from the layout and also with Swiss binding.

I have a ViewModel that has a propriety ShouldShowBackButton:

```
  public class TabViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private bool _showBackButton;

        public IMvxCommand NavigateCommand => new MvxCommand(this.Act, this.CanAct);

        public bool ShouldShowBackButton
        {
            get => this._showBackButton;

            set
            {
                this._showBackButton = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ShouldShowBackButton);
            }
        }

        private void Act()
        {
            this.ShowViewModel<ProfileFragmentViewModel>();
        }

        private bool CanAct()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

this ViewModel is inhereted of the actual ViewModel:

```
 public class ProfileFragmentViewModel : TabViewModel
    {
        public ProfileFragmentViewModel()
        {
            this.ShouldShowBackButton = false;
        }
    }
```

The viewModel is correctly binded to the View, I`ve already tested it.
This is the way I am trying to make the TextView invisible:

```
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/testProp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="Test visibility"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(ShouldShowBackButton)" />
```

And also, the Swiss code:

```
 public class ProfileFragmentView : MvxFragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ProfileFragmentView, null);
            var backButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.toolbarBackButton);
            var testButton = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.testProp);
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ProfileFragmentView, ProfileFragmentViewModel>();

            set.Bind(testButton).For(v => v.Visibility).To(vm => vm.ShouldShowBackButton)
                .WithConversion<MvxVisibilityValueConverter>();

            set.Apply();
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Neither of the methods does make my TextView invisible.

Comment: can you post your entire ProfileFragmentView layout file?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare you property as reactive

```
[Reactive]
public bool ShouldShowBackButton
    {
        get => this._showBackButton;
       ....
```

Comment: This attribute is not found, maybe it is from another version of MvvmCross.

Comment: @Kam My bad, I always use MvvmCross with ReactiveUI . The annotation is from the latter library

Comment: Q: does xmlns:local: points to ""http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto""?

Comment: @Kam, is what @MihaiBC just asked the solution? I can't reproduce your problem when I add `xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: I use it as xmlns:app=&quot;....&quot; and later app:MvxBind=&quot;Visibility Visibility...
Maybe you can try like that

Comment: This was the solution of one of my problems. The main solution of this problem was that instead of  "local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(ShouldShowBackButton)"" I used " local:MvxBind="Visible ShouldShowBackButton""

Comment: do you know how that could be done in case the view is being generated in c#?

Comment: Considering that it extends a Widget you will have the set the parent value for visibility pragmatically while creating the button